# connecting the log in form in vb.net (adodb.connection usage)

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have this code in log in form, but I don't know the use of `adodb.connection`, please anyone help me to fix it. I don't know why the word `adodb` to me has an zigzag error line.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Public Class LoginForm1
Dim rs_login As New adodb.Recordset
Dim cn_login As New adodb.Connection
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles   OK.Click
    rs_login = cn_login.Execute("select * from dbo.studentinfo where [Username] = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' And [Password] = '" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'")
    If rs_login.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Username!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        rs_login = cn_login.Execute("select * from dbo.USERPASS where [Username] = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' And [Password] = '" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'")
        If rs_login.RecordCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Username", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            user.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel.Click
    Me.Close()
    Home.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SI.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub LoginForm1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With cn_login
        .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        .Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1"
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        Dim con As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=Danica-pc; database=SI;user=dandan;pwd=danica;"}
        .Open()

    End With
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you missing a reference?  Also, your code is wide open to sql injection as is.

Comment: uhm pardon me. wat do you mean by that?

Comment: Goto your project, right click "add a reference", find and select 'ADODB'. I suggested you investigate sql injection as you have not sanitised any user input, a user could drop your entire database by injecting their own sql into your queries. There are plenty of guides online detailing how to prevent this.

Comment: uhm i had my user input and i want to get username and password, which the user put his username and password

Answer (score 0):

You are using a database access code written for VBA. Probably for MS Access. In VB.NET this works very differently. You would use this `Imports` statement:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

In VB.NET you would do something like this

```vb
Const StandardSecurityConnection As String = _
    "Server=Danica-pc;Database=SI;User Id=dandan;Password=danica;"
Const TrustedConnection As String = _
    "Server=Danica-pc;Database=SI;Trusted_Connection=True;"

Using conn As New SqlConnection(StandardSecurityConnection) 'Or TrustedConnection
    Dim sql As String = _
        "SELECT * FROM dbo.studentinfo WHERE Username = @usr AND Password = @pwd"
    Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", UsernameTextBox.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", PasswordTextBox.Text)
        conn.Open()
        Using dr As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim userCol AS Integer = dr.GetOrdinal("Username")
            Dim pwdCol AS Integer = dr.GetOrdinal("Password")
            While dr.Read()
                ConSole.WriteLine("User = {0}, Password = {1}", 
                    dr.GetString(userCol), dr.GetString(pwdCol))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: where did i put this?

Comment: it is under by ok click button?
or this is might be the whole proper program in log in?

Comment: This is an example of how you can query a SQL Server table with VB.NET. Adapt it to your specific problem. That would go into the click button, but it's only reading records and printing them out in the console. I did not reprogram your complete logic.

Comment: why is my trustedconnection has a zizag line color green?

Comment: Green squiggly lines are warnings. The code still compiles. Hover with the mouse over it. It will probably show a messsage telling you that the constant is defined but never used. That's ok, I've just shown you two possible connections strings. You need only one of them.

Comment: If you want to test whether the user exists, you can replace my While-Loop with `If dr.Read() Then 'User exists and Pwd is correct`.